# solid border displaying as double depending on size of browser window

Tags: html, css, border

I have a header with a border on the left and right side of it and for some reason, depending on the width of my browser window, the border switches from solid to double. When I inspect the element, the css shows that it is still 'solid' but it displays as double. When changing the style to any other border-style, it appears as a double border.

[border issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxm91.png)

```css
.line-header {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.line {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: fit-content;
}

.line::before,
.line::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid #000; */
}

.line::before {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient( to left, black, white) 1 0%;
}

.line::after {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient( to right, black, white) 1 0%;
}

.line:not(:empty)::before {
  margin-right: .5em;
  /* adjusts left margin between line and text */
}

.line:not(:empty)::after {
  margin-left: .5em;
  /* adjusts right margin between line and text */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row line-header">
    <div class="line">AIR CHECKS</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row air-checks">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <audio src="" controls id="audioPlayer">
                          Sorry, your browser doesn't support HTML5!
                     </audio>
    <br>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle audio-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                               Air Checks<span class="caret"></span>
                          </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-center" id="playlist">

      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/audioPlayer.js"></script>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row line-header">
    <div class="line">RECAP IMAGES</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(now works with the gradient)

Instead of using `border-width: 1px`, use `border-bottom-width: 1px`, and dito for all the other border styles. The problem was that it was creating a top and a bottom border, hence the apparent "double border".

```css
.line-header {
padding-bottom: 50px;
font-size: 32px; 
display: flex;
}

.line {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    flex-grow:1;
    width: fit-content;
}

.line::before,
.line::after {
    content: '';
    flex: 1;
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid #000; */
}

.line::before {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient( to left, black, white ) 1 0%;
}

.line::after {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient( to right, black, white ) 1 0%;
}

.line:not(:empty)::before {
    margin-right: .5em; /* adjusts left margin between line and text */
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="row line-header">
                <div class="line">AIR CHECKS</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="row air-checks">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                 <audio src="" controls id="audioPlayer" >
                      Sorry, your browser doesn't support HTML5!
                 </audio>
                 <br>
                 <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle audio-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                           Air Checks<span class="caret"></span>
                      </button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-center" id="playlist">
                
                      </ul>
                   </div>
                  <script src="assets/audioPlayer.js"></script>
           </div>
    </div>

<div class="container">
     <div class="row line-header">
          <div class="line">RECAP IMAGES</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This fixes the double line issue but breaks the gradient effect. It seems like "border-bottom-image" is an unknown property.

Comment: UPDATE: It works if I change all the borders to "border-bottom" except for "border-image"! Thank you!

Comment: Okay, I updated the "border-image" to do the gradient again. Good eye!